# Disabling submit button until all fields have values is not Working

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new at using jquery and just copied the jquery code.

The jquery disables the Sumbit button if the all of the field in the form is not filled. 
The form is already filled with data from a table but the submit button is still diabled.

Where did i go wrong?

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);

session_start();
include('dbconn.php');  
$admin_ID   = $_SESSION['admin_ID'];

if (empty($_SESSION['admin_ID']) && parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) != '../index.php') {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit;
}



$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_ID='$admin_ID'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

if (!$query) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
    $('form input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#Submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        } else {
            $('#Submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        }
    });
})()




        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/sbma.png" class="logo" id="logo"></img>
            <a style = "float:left;">My Account</a>
            <a href="MainMenu.php">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">

        </div>
        <div id="section">
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
            <form class="form-style-1" action="MyUpdateProcess.php" method="post">
                <ul>
                <fieldset class="fieldset-company">
                    <li>
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='username' id='input'  value = "<?php echo $row1['admin_Username'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type='password' name='password' id='input' value="<?php echo $row1['admin_Password'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>First Name:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='fname' id='input'  value = "<?php echo $row1['admin_Fname'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Middle Name:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='mname' id='input' value="<?php echo $row1['admin_Mname'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                                        <li>
                        <label>Last Name:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='lname' id='input'  value = "<?php echo $row1['admin_Lname'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="fieldset-contacts">                    
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='email' id='input' value="<?php echo $row1['admin_Email'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Telephone:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='telephone' id='input' value="<?php echo $row1['admin_Telephone'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Mobile:</label>
                        <input type='text' name='mobile' id='input'  value = "<?php echo $row1['admin_Mobile'];?>" maxlength="50" />
                    </li>
            <?php endwhile;?>                   


                </fieldset>
                    <li>
                      <input id="Submit" type='Submit' disabled="disabled" name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
    S.B.M.A Centralized Information System 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you tried `$("#Submit").prop("disabled", false);` and also print the `empty' value before checking the condition to ensure that the previous part is working or not

Comment: You might also want to do your validation in the $(form).submit() function so you don't have to check all the inputs on keyUp.

Comment: I tried it but the Submit is still disabled

Answer (score 2):

`$('form > input')` means IMMEDIATE child.

`$('form input')` means any descendant.

None of your input elements are immediate children of the form element.

Change to `$('form input')`.

There are other changes, such as using `prop` instead of `attr` that will help. As well as binding to both `keyup` and `change` events.

```
(function() {
    $('form input').on('keyup change', function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#Submit').prop('disabled', true); 
        } else {
            $('#Submit').prop('disabled', false); 
        }
    });

    $('form input:eq(0)').keyup(); // run the check
})()
```

But even this will not work. Why? Because your while loop prints out more than one `<form>` element without ever closing them. You have a form inside a form inside a form etc etc, depending on how many loops there are. This will cause unexpected behavior. You need to decide how you really want to handle the while loop, and ensure the forms are printed out properly.

Also, submit element only submits the one form that it's in. So maybe you should only have one more?

Also, **the HTML id must be unique**! You must remove `id="input"` from all of those inputs or else you'll get even more unexpected behavior.

Comment: The code has way more problems than I thought upon further inspection, I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do following,

$('form input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {

```
    var empty = false;
    $('form input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#Submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    } else {
        $('#Submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
    }
```

or add a class to the text boxes and check whether those classes having value or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form input').each(function() {

            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#Submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        } else {
            $('#Submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet...

Why don't you just add the "required" attribute to all of your input fields like that :`<input required type='text' name='username' id='input'  value = "<?php echo $row1['admin_Username'];?>" maxlength="50" />`
                ? The button will never be disabled but it won't do anything until each field is filled.

Comment: haha yeah that works 

but i still wanna know why my code won't work

Comment: Yeah I know that's not what you asked. That's why I would have commented instead of answered if I had the choice ;) I'll just let JS experts help you with your code :)